# What is the type of null?

Tags: kotlin, types, null

In Kotlin, the type of something that can be either `Foo or null is Foo?.

But what is the type of null itself? In particular, it is *not* an element of Any, or any subtype thereof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the spec](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#null-literal):

> The keyword `null` denotes the null reference, which represents an absence of a value and is a valid value only for nullable types. Null reference has type `kotlin.Nothing?` and is, by definition, the only value of this type.

This is relevant for example here:

```kotlin
fun foo() = null
```

Kotlin will infer the return type of `foo` from its body, which is the expression `null`. Hence the return type will be `kotlin.Nothing?`.

Edit: Assignment of `null` to nullable types works because

> `kotlin.Nothing` is the subtype of any other type in Kotlin type system

And therefore, for any `T`, `kotlin.Nothing?` is assignable to `T?` since `kotlin.Nothing` is a subtype of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

`null` it's not a specific type, but instead defines a value for some variables that have specific types.

`null` defines a reference to nothing or to an empty memory address.

Comment: `null` is an expression and as expression it does have a type.

Comment: null is not an expression. Reading the definition of "expression": "An expression in a programming language is a syntactic entity that may be evaluated to determine its value.", we can easily come to the conclusion that null is not an expression.

Comment: That definition proves that `null` *is* an expression.